# jQuery - can I fill form inputs from a serialized form string?

Tags: jquery, query-string, form-fields, auto-populating, form-processing

Given that I have some form on a page, I know I can get a unicode serialized string using

```
var query = jQuery('#some-form').serialize();
```

It's also possible setting the value of each input with `$('#some-input').val(...)`. Assuming that same form above was reset, but I still have the query string - is there a simple way to populate the form from that string? I realize I could parse it and set every input/select individually, but I was looking for a simpler solution. Thanks.

Comment: Can we do some thing like jQuery('#FormID').val(earlySerializedState);.. expecting to populate all form fields as per the serializedState variable?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could serialize the form into a JSON array and use an MVVM mapping plugin like [Knockout.js](http://www.knockoutjs.com) to auto-fill the form.

See [Serializing to JSON in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery/912247#912247)

Answer (score 1):

[jquery.deserialize plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/deserialize) should help you.

Comment: just tried, but it seems to not work with multiple select inputs. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your form only contains text inputs (not as arrays), you may try this plugin, which I've adapted from its unserialize function counterpart (https://gist.github.com/rcmachado/242617#file-jquery-unserialize-js), but instead of returning an object, it fills the form it applies to.

```
(function($){
    $.fn.fillformwithserialized = function(serializedString) {
        var str = decodeURI(serializedString);
        var pairs = str.split('&');
        var p, idx, val;
        for (var i=0, n=pairs.length; i < n; i++) {
            p = pairs[i].split('=');
            idx = p[0];

            var txtBox = this.find('#' + idx + ':input');
            if (txtBox.is(":text")) {
                txtBox.val(p[1]);
            }
        }

        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Example of use:

```
var dataSerialised = sessionStorage.getItem('frmVeryImportantStuff');

if (dataSerialised == null || !confirm("We could restore the previous version of the form you posted. Shall we?"))
return false;
else {
    $("#frmVeryImportantStuff").fillformwithserialized(dataSerialised);
}
```

Obviously you'll need to have saved your form in the sessionStorage in the first place.
Example:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("frmVeryImportantStuff", $(frmVeryImportantStuff).serialize());
```